# IndexError: list index out of range error for python split function

Tags: python, split, pi

Hey guys I am sending load cell data to my raspberry PI via Arduino. The Arduino sends out data to serial in chunks like this:

```
0,0  
2,3  
5,6  
0,0
```

So what I want to do is split the left reading from the right reading using the split function and the following python code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

while True:
   
    read_serial=ser.readline()
    x = read_serial
    y = x.split(",")
    left = y[0]
    right = y[1]
    print(left)
    print(' ')
    print(right)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "arduino_communication.py", line 10, in <module>
    right = y[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I comment out that line and also comment out `right = y[1]` I get the reading of the left load cell correctly. So I'm a bit unsure of what the reason is as to why I'm not able to get the right load cell (which has been split into position 1 of an array)

Comment: Perhaps some `x` doesn't contain a comma. Print `x` before splitting to make sure.

Comment: There is no comma in your `x` string, so it can't be split in two. Print it and see how it looks.

Comment: maybe it is an empty line

Comment: the data im sending through serial is givin in the info.. it comes out as 0,0 or if theres weight on the load cell it will be something like 30,31

Answer (score 0):

maybe serial data hasn't comma or empty string.
print x before splitting.

If sometimes serial data hasn't comma or empty string, use try/except please.

```
try:
   y = x.split(",")
   left = y[0]
   right = y[1]
except IndexError:
   right = 0(or use the other value)
```

Comment: when i just do print(x) this is the data that comes out to the terminal:

30,29   

29,28   

28,27

Comment: I think this ended up fixing the program, it ended up printing \r\n at the end of the line but this finishing code did the trick!!

'''
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

while True:
   
    read_serial=ser.readline()
    x = read_serial
    try:
     y = x.split(",")
     left = y[0]
     right = y[1]
     rightFixed = right.replace("\r\n","")
     #print(x)
     print(left, rightFixed)
     #print(' a')
     #print(right)
    except IndexError:
     right = 0
'''

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your python script is trying to read the serial line faster than your arduino is writing values, which means that sometimes the python script reads the serialline as an empty string like this: ''.

If you put all the code inside a try/block, the code will only run when the arduino actually has wrote some values.

Hopefully this will help you:

```
while True:
    try:
        read_serial=ser.readline()
        x = read_serial
        y = x.split(",")
        left = y[0]
        right = y[1]
        print(left)
        print(' ')
        print(right)
    except Exception as e:
        raise
```